# Regex pattern with a slash

Tags: c#, regex

I have  a property such as IdentityCode

```
string IdentityCode {get;set;}
```

my IdentityCode has three pattern 
it has 6 digit

```
######---->332145
```

or can get 6 digit with a slash

```
######/#----->332145/1
######/##----->332145/15
```

How can I set a pattern for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
"\d{6}(/\d{1,2})?"
```

The expression matches 6 digits with an optional slash + one or two digits at the end.

Comment: Note that there are up to *two* digits after the slash. Also, I don't think you can use `\d` like that in a string literal in C#.

Comment: @ruakh Yeah, he may need to add `@` or double his slashes.

Answer (score 7):

Slashes are not special in .Net regexes, so you can just write `/`.

More fully:

```
@"\d{6}(/\d{1,2})?"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one or two digits at the end then you need this

```
"\d{6}(/\d{1,2})?"
```